# ASP.NET MVC5,An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to add a object to db,it's appears a mistake as followed:

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.*

Here is my code:

Order.cs

```
namespace OnlineMealOrdering.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string UserTEL { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantTEL { get; set; }
        public string Memo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderDetail.cs

```
namespace OnlineMealOrdering.Models
{
    public class OrderDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public Dish Dish { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cart.cs

```
public class Cart
{
    public Dish Dish { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers

```
public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private OnlineMealOrderingContext db = new OnlineMealOrderingContext();

        List<Cart> Carts
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["Carts"] == null)
                {
                    Session["Carts"] = new List<Cart>();
                }
                return (Session["Carts"] as List<Cart>);
            }
            set { Session["Carts"] = value; }
        }

 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Submit(string memo)
            {
                int user_id = (Session["Account"] as Account).Id;
                var user = (from p in db.Users
                            where p.Id == user_id
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
                var restaurant = this.Carts.FirstOrDefault().Dish.Restaurant;
                int total_price = 0;
                foreach (var item in this.Carts)
                {
                    total_price += item.Dish.Price * item.Count;
                }
                Order order = new Order
                {
                    User = user,
                    Restaurant = restaurant,
                    TotalPrice = total_price,
                    OrderTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Address = user.Address,
                    UserTEL = user.TEL,
                    RestaurantTEL = restaurant.TEL,
                    Memo = memo,
                    OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>()
                };

                foreach (var item in this.Carts)
                {
                    order.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail() { Dish = item.Dish, Price = item.Dish.Price, Count = item.Count });
                }
```

> db.Orders.Add(order);

```
                db.SaveChanges();

                this.Carts.Clear();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

}

It happened in red area statement.

Comment: What exactly is this.Carts?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch,I'm update the question already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell, since you didn't include all your entities, but since your "Dish" object comes from a List stored in Session, I'm guessing Dish was pulled from the database as well.  If so, it may belong to a different instance of the DbContext, so when you try to add it to your Orders it complains because Dish already is being tracked by your previous instance.

Incidentally, this is why storing things you get from your DbContext in a session is a bad idea.. plus it can keep references around and lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Uh,what is the most convenient method of modification.

Comment: @DrakFlameMaster - I have no idea how the rest of your app works.. so it's impossible for me to say.  You should probably just retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: I've solved the problem,you're right.It's the problem of session.